# Set a static field value in ADODB.RecordSet in VB6

Tags: sql, vb6, adodb, recordset

Is it possible to set the value of a static field from a query in ADODB Recordset in VB6?

For example, say I have a recordset whose source is:

```
SELECT col1, col2, '' AS staticCol
FROM myTable
WHERE 1 = 2
```

and then I add a new record by calling `myRS.AddNew`.

In the new record, all three fields are NULL. I can set col1 and col2 with no issues:

```
myRS.Fields("col1").Value = "one"
myRS.Fields("col2").Value = "two"
```

But when I try to set staticCol, I get an error.

```
myRS.Fields("staticCol").Value = "three"
-->Run-time error '-2147217887 (80040e21)':
-->Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.
myRS.Fields("staticCol").Value = ""
-->Run-time error '-2147217887 (80040e21)':
-->Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.
```

Is there any way to make this work? I'd prefer to keep the active connection open if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to actually look at the errors, you'll find them in the Errors collection of the Connection object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two fields are mapped to fields in the database. You have a table called myTable, and the fields are mapped to col1 and col2. The third value, however, is specified as an empty string. Think of it as a Const in your SQL. You cannot assign a new value to a const: it is always the same value that it was before.

Even if you could do so: which field would it be mapped to? The database can't know where you want it to go. It thinks that you're trying to insert into a field and is reporting that it cannot perform that operation for you.

My VB6 is rusty, and I no longer own a copy, but I am wondering why you are trying to add a record in that fashion. It is better practice to write an INSERT stored procedure, and call it as you would any other procedure.

Comment: Marked as answered because I'm taking away from your answer that no, it cannot be done. The reason why I want to do it this way is rather complex so I won't go into it here.